# Fast conversion from std::string to std::vector<bool>

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

**Edit:** I am leaving the original question below, but the conversion is not as slow as I claimed. There is a bug in my original program that caused the function to be called with a much longer input than I intended. Indeed, converting from a `string` to a bit `vector` only takes about 1.5x as long as converting the other way.

---

I need to convert a string to `vector<bool>`. The conversion is very slow, however. I understand that `vector<bool>` is a specialization of vector. I tried using `vector<char>` instead, but that is just as slow.

This is my code:

```
std::vector<bool> frombytes(const std::string &bytes)
{
    std::vector<bool> output;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < bytes.length(); i++)
    {
        unsigned char byte = bytes[i];
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            output.push_back(byte >> (7 - j) & 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I am thinking that perhaps by writing 8 bits at a time, I can make this faster. However, I can't figure out a way to do so. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

**More information:**

- I have tried `vector::reserve`, but that did not make much difference.
- I am compiling the program using g++ with the "`-O3`" flag.

Comment: Have you considered pre-allocating the output buffer?

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but that did not help much.

Comment: How do you know this is slow btw? What is "slow" exactly? How do you benchmark?

Comment: @Mike Yeo Use the method reserve for the vector.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I tried a conversion from std::vector<bool> to a string, and that is almost 8 times as fast. I don't really see a reason why conversion from string to std::vector<bool> should be so much slower, though perhaps there could be a reason that I might missed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thanks for your comment. I tried that already, but it did not make much of a difference.

Comment: Did you remember to enable optimisation?

Comment: @eerorika Yes, I did. I realized I should have included more details in my original question. Let me do that.

Comment: [std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) is an option.

Comment: *"a conversion from std::vector<bool> to a string, and that is almost 8 times as fast"* -- I notice that, assuming the same underlying data, the string will have 1/8 the number of elements as the vector. So creating the string that is 1/8 the size of the vector takes 1/8 the time of creating the vector.  Coincidence?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I think I might not have understood what you meant. I don't quite see how to use std::transform as I am converting a single character of the string to 8 elements in the vector.

Comment: @JaMiT I certainly agree that the vector has 8 times as many elements as the string, but conversion both ways involves accessing the vector of bools and accessing the string. The only difference is that in the first case, we are writing to the vector of bools and reading from the string, and the other way around in the second case. Perhaps there is a difference between reading and writing that results in the difference in time, but I don't quite see it.

Comment: @MikeYeo can you post how you're measuring your speed or what your exact benchmark is (with test data) so that people can replicate and show noticeable improvement instead of waiting on you to confirm/deny if their suggestion works for you?

Comment: @ffledgling Thank you for your comment. Unexpectedly, I was not able to reproduce the results when I got rid of the rest of the program and used a minimal example. I am still trying to figure out what is going on here.

Comment: @MikeYeo No, it's not the same in both directions. Conversion in one direction involves accessing the vector of `bool` and *building* the string, while conversion in the other direction involves accessing the string, while *building* the vector of `bool`. Building involves allocating new memory and copying/moving data from the old allocation to the new. Much more work than simply reading from pre-existing data. (That's why `reserve` was quickly mentioned in the comments.)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. I have found a bug in my program which caused frombytes to be called with a much longer string as input, resulting in it taking much a longer time than expected. I will be closing this question.

Comment: @JaMiT Indeed, converting from bytes to bits is still slightly slower than from bits, but the difference is not as significant as what I claimed earlier.

Comment: I realize I am unable to close the question, so I have made some edits to the question to clarify and will be leaving it as it is.

Comment: @MikeYeo - if you look at the bottom of the page with the link provided, you will see an example transforming a string to upper case. If your string is a string of `'0'` and `'1'`, you can transform the string into a vector of `bool` by returning `true/false` based on the character and use the result to populate your vector of `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that such a conversion is necessary. You can use simple accessor functions to get hold of individual bits, and you can write simple custom iterators that expose bits in a string as if they were individual bools. That completely sidesteps the cost of conversion. The conversion is very wasteful because internally the `vector<bool>` will be usually implemented as a vector of unsigned chars or integers, with special accessors that twiddle bits of those. It is highly likely that the memory representation of the data in the `vector<bool>` and `std::string` will be identical with possible exception of bit and/or byte order. So if you seem to care about performance so much, then skipping the whole brouhaha makes most sense.

The accessors are dead simple:

```
bool getBit(size_t index, const std::string &str)
{
  assert(index/8 < str.size());
  return (str[index/8] >> (index%8)) & 1;
}

void setBit(size_t const index, bool const val, std::string &str)
{
  assert(index/8 < str.size());
  char c = str[index/8];
  c &= ~(1 << (index%8));
  c |= char(val) << (index % 8);
  str[index/8] = c;
}
```

If you want to iterate the string as bits, you could use the following iterator adapter (untested):

```
template <typename Container>
class const_bit_iterator {
  using c_value_type = const Container::value_type;
  using iterator = Container::const_iterator;
  static constexpr size_t modulus = 8u * sizeof(c_value_type );
  size_t index = 0;
  iterator it = {};
  constexpr c_value_type bitmask() const { return c_value_type (1) << (index % modulus); }
public:
  using value_type = const bool;
  struct end_tag_t {};
  static constexpr end_tag_t end_tag = {};
  explicit bit_iterator(const Container &container) : it(container.begin()) {}
  explicit bit_iterator(end_tag_t, const Container &container) :
    index(modulus * container.size()), it(container.end()) {}
  bool operator*() const { return get(); }
  bool get() const { return (*it) & bitmask(); }
  bit_iterator &operator++() {
    ++ index;
    if (!(index % modulus)) ++ it;
    return *this;
  }
  bit_iterator operator++(int) {
    auto it = *this;
    ++ *this;
    return it;
  }
  bit_iterator &operator--() {
    -- index;
    if ((index % modulus) == (modulus - 1)) -- it;
    return *this;
  }
  bit_iterator operator--(int) {
    auto it = *this;
    -- *this;
    return it;
  }
  bool operator==(const bit_iterator &o) const { return index == o.index; }
  bool operator!=(const bit_iterator &o) const { return index != o.index; }
  bool operator<(const bit_iterator &o) const { return index < o.index; }
};
```

```
template <typename Container>
class const_bit_adapter
{
  const Container &ref;
public:
  const_bit_adapter(const Container &container) : ref(container) {}
  const_bit_iterator begin() const { return const_bit_iterator(ref); }
  const_bit_iterator end() const { return const_bit_iterator(const_bit_iterator::end_tag, ref); }
};

template <typename Container>
const_bit_adapter<Container> as_const_bits(const Container &container)
{ return {container}; }
template <typename Container>
const_bit_adapter<Container> as_bits(const Container &container)
{ return {container}; }
```

Example use:

```
std::vector<int> bits(32);
size_t n = 0;
for (bool b : as_const_bits(bits))
  ++n;
assert(n == bits.size() * 8u * sizeof(decltype(bits)::value_type));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a couple of different ways namely using a table and a switch to make it faster. Here are the results:

1. [Results using switch](http://quick-bench.com/nPGmyCoAj0MLAHaWN3ZDJVN_Pw4)
2. [Results using table](http://quick-bench.com/MALDvmW3uTniS1EMtIclXqHEhew)

Results are separate due to character limit in quickbench.

---

- Using switch and returning `std::array` is almost `1.8` times faster than the original version.
- Using table was about `1.6 - 1.7` times faster than the original version.
- Using `std::vector<bool>` is slighty slower than using `std::vector<unsigned char>`

Code used to generate the table and switch(with a little modification):

```
std::vector<bool> frombytes(int byte)
{
    std::vector<bool> output;
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            output.push_back(byte >> (7 - j) & 1);
        }
    return output;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "{\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {  
        auto bits = frombytes(i);
        /* std::cout << "case " << i <<":\n"; */
        std::cout << "    {";
        int cnt = 0;
        for (auto b : bits) {
            cnt++;
            if (cnt == 8)
                std::cout << b;
            else
                std::cout << b << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << "},\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n};\n";   
    return 0;
}
```